# can't call class with alertdialog

Tags: android

I've got this code to create a alert dialog with clickable links using a textview:

```
    public static class MyOtherAlertDialog {

         public static AlertDialog create(Context context) {
          final TextView message = new TextView(context);
          // i.e.: R.string.dialog_message =>
                    // "Test this dialog following the link to dtmilano.blogspot.com"
          final SpannableString s = 
                       new SpannableString(context.getText(R.string.dialog_about));
          Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
          message.setText(s);
          message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

          return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
           .setTitle(R.string.about)
           .setCancelable(true)
           .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
           .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
           .setView(message)
           .create();
         }
        }
```

But I don't know exactly how to call it,

I've tried:

```
                  MyOtherAlertDialog variable = new MyOtherAlertDialog();
                  variable.create(this);
```

But without luck, how should I call this class?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
AlertDialog dialog = MyOtherAlertDialog.create(this);
dialog.show();
```

This is rather basic java.  If you need to ask this question, maybe you should start by learning some basics.

Comment: Thank you, worked. I'm trying to learn java, but I prefer to just learn it by playing with it. (I'll accept your answer asap.)

Answer (score 0):

To show the dialog try using this

```
MyOtherAlertDialog.create(this).show();
```

Actually the `Dialog` is created from your code but it is not shown as you are not calling `show()` method.

And as the `create`() method is `static` so you should access it in a `static` way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by StinePike and Alejs G is right. Just want to add that you have declared the `create` method `static`. Thus, you need to use class name to call that method.
That is why it should be

`MyOtherAlertDialog.create(this);`

Same concept applies for variables.